# Does the mobile device under test need to have an ip-address to use appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

Will the device under test need to have wifi enabled so it gets an ip address before we can use appium to connect to a port on the device or is it possible to connect to and run tests with wi-fi off and if so, what ip address would we use to talk to the socket server on the device ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can connect your device through wi-fi and run your appium tests. Below are the steps:

1. Your device and Machine/Laptop needs to be in the same network.
2. Connect your device through USB and enter following command :`adb tcpip 5555`
   (This enables the tcpip port 5555).

   You should get the output as `restarting in TCP mode port: 5555`
3. Now you can disconnect your device which is connected through the USB.
4. Open wi-fi setting in the device and note down the ip address of device.
5. In the command prompt on the machine, enter the following command to connect your device: `adb connect 192.168.0.2:5555` (IP ADDRESS SHOUD BE YOURS)

You should the output as: `connected to 192:268.0.2:5555`

6. Now, Enter `adb devices` to check whether the device is connected or not. Your device should be listed in the output of "adb devices" command with ip address.
7. Use the same ip address along with port number as UDID capability. eg. `192:268.0.2:5555`

**Note: If you restart your device then you need to enable the tcpip port as mentioned in step 2.**

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Appreciate it!